# range normalized with unclear highest value

Tags: normalization, java

I tried to normalize many set, which each set consists of 12 values. I want to normalize it into range between 1 and -1. However, the highest value is unclear because the value can be trillion, or even more. I code it using java.

can somebody help me what to do? I tried to normalize it using standard deviation but the result is not satisfying.

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need it to be a linear rescaling, or are nonlinear, but monotonic transformations okay?

Comment: I guess linear rescaling, but I don't quite understand about what is monotonic transformations?

Comment: Monotonic transformations will preserve the original ordering of the observations, but nor the relative distances between them. An example: imagine observations which are restricted to be positive and consider $t(x) = \frac{x-1}{x+1}$. Then $t$ lies between -1 and 1. But consider evenly spaced values (2,3,4). They will transform to (1/3, 1/2 and 3/5), which are no longer equally spaced.

Comment: Then no matter which limit you choose, it could be exceeded by the next set of 12.

Comment: Depends on what do you need it to do, what you can live without if you must, and perhaps what you can say about the process.

Comment: If you can clarify your understanding of your question further, you may get some interesting answers. Are you interested in probabilistic bounds, for example (e.g. ones which are very likely to be sufficient, but which will fail occasionally and need to be recalculated)?

Comment: You cannot really expect an answer without telling us more of your applied modelling context! What is the real problem you are trying to solve?